# meaning of でも～くらい

Tags: grammar

I cannot understand what is 自分でも無様なくらいに means in the following sentence. I'd translate it like - "I felt so akward, that my voice trembled"

> 自分でも無様なくらいに声が震えていた

Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to connect でも～くらい into one construction. Rather you're looking at [自分でも][無様なくらいに][声が震えてきた]

So if you break that down it's just basically [even me][to an unsightly (or whatever you want to translate it as) degree][voice started trembling]

Note that it is 無様+な+くらい, so it's using くらい as amount/degree and using 無様 as a simple na-adjective to describe the extent.

The translation that you offered is slightly off. 無様 refers to how the trembling voice made the speaker look, not to what caused the trembling in the first place. So it would be closer to something like "Even my voice started trembling awkwardly," to use your choice of awkward.